# Photos Library Edited Photos Location

Tags: macos, photos.app, plex

I am trying to use Plex to share my family's photo library (Photos.app) so it's available on any device to view photos. The problem is that adding the entire Photos library to Plex's library results in multiple, differing copies of the same image.

QUESTION: Is there a location inside the Photos library package where there are organized sets of photos (edited, not originals), such that I could add a folder to a Plex library, or is there any good/better way to do this?